# Geo Nodes: Combining vector rotations

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry, vector

I'm trying to get instances to rotate to face the centre of a mesh circle.
I've had success getting them to orientate correctly when the circle is created using the distance between points on X or Y, but not a combination of both. How do I combine these rotations so that I can create the circle using X and Y. Any help on this would be appreciated!

(This is my first post here, I can't see how to upload the blender file - any tips on that and I'll upload it)

[image: Working as intended when the empty is translated on Y]

[image: Not working when the empty is translated on X]

Comment: Your question is clear without a blend file. The solution lies in the correct chaining of the "align euler to vector" nodes. Take the output of the y-axis rotation socket and plug it into the x-axis rotation socket.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do your rotations at 0, and _then_ transform according to your Pivot object, like this.. https://imgur.com/a/1Wz8Jq1  ?

Answer (score 0):

you should plug one of them (align euler to vector) into the others rotation input.

set the second ones *pivot* (the dropdown) to whatever the *axis* (the the options on top x,y,z) of the previous one is.

---

[image]